# How can I find the average of a single grade, and then of multiple grades in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, average

I am trying to make a program that will take ask for the grade recieved, the total on the assignment, then average this. They keep doing this till they want to stop, at which point they will input -1. I cannot get it to average correctly, it is always coming out as 0.00, I'm new to C so I am sure it is a simple oversight, Thank you for any help you can offer.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    int main( void )
   {
    unsigned int counter;
    int grade;
    int total;
    int asavg;
    int asavgv;

    float average;

    total = 0;
    counter = 0;

    printf("%s", "Enter grade, -1 to end: " );
    scanf("%d", &grade );

    printf("Enter total possible: ");
    scanf("%d", &asavg );

    asavgv = grade / asavg;

    while ( grade !=-1) {
        total = total + asavgv;
        counter = counter + 1;

        printf ("%s", "Enter grade -1 to end: ");
        scanf("%d" , &grade);


        printf("Enter total possible: ");
        scanf("%d", &asavg );

        asavgv = grade / asavg;
    }

    if ( counter != 0 ) {

        average = ( float ) total / counter;

        printf("Average is %.2f\n", average );
    }
    else {
        puts("no grades were entered");
    }
     getch();
    }
```

Comment: If you are new to C then I suggest you start making friends with the dwebugger

Comment: Counter is one less than the number of actual.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int asavgv;
```

to

```
double asavgv;
```

and then do

```
asavgv = grade*1.0 / asavg;
```

or

```
asavgv = (double)grade / asavg;
```

Comment: Doing that still gave me the average being 0.00.

Comment: @Austin123457: Try to understand your problem instead of just copying solutions presented here.  Do you know the differences between `int`, `float` and `double`?  Do you know that in C, `3 / 2` is `1`, whereas `3.0 / 2` and `3 / 2.0` are `1.5`?

Comment: I am trying to understand my problem, but when the answer is merely Put this like this, and then do this, I don't have much to work with, and so I answered specifically what it did. My book I am working out of hasn't touched on Double integers yet, so I do not know for sure what they are. I posted here so that way I could understand my problem and then learn from it.